# Allow multiple GET requests to a Flask server that runs a node.js script

Tags: python, node.js, flask

I am trying to have WebCORE (smartthings) run a Get request to run a node.js script [EufyNodeClient](https://github.com/JanLoebel/eufy-node-client) and change the security mode for my cameras.

I have successfully installed the eufynode script and am able to execute the .js file from the terminal.

I successfully used a [WebCORE piston](https://community.webcore.co/t/executing-a-scrip-on-my-raspberry-pi/9815/2) using flask and an executable python script to run the node. With Flask installed, when I start Flask in the terminal, flask starts and the script runs but I cannot make another request via HTTP Get request.

I can also repeatedly run the Flask and python script using Thonny Python IDE with or without starting the Flask server in the terminal.

I am a super noobie and have been able to get this far with searching and reading but now I'm stuck.
Is there a way to have Flask in the background and still accept an incoming request to change the security mode? This setup is just for me and would stay inside my network so if I don't need a production server, that would be great.

**Here is my Flask app:**

```
from flask import Flask
from home import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/home/pi/eufy-node-client-examples/')

def mode_setting():
    return home.mode_subprocess()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app.run()
```

**and python script**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import run
run(["node", "examples/p2p-local/index.js"])
```